# Angular 5 understanding errorResponse if options request fails

Tags: angular, http-error

In my angular 5 application if I have a malformed URL like you see in the picture and if I make a GET request I see a failed option request and if it fails my request has an error status = 0, like connection refused but it is not actually the same thing.

So I need to differentiate these errors because in this case I need to show something different from "Connection refused".

Is it possible to do it, maybe avoiding option request to fails like this or maybe with some nested error property in the ErrorResponse?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for error details?

In the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details) there is a part about it:

```
private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
    console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
  } else {
    // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
    // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
    console.error(
      `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
      `body was: ${error.error}`);
  }
  // return an ErrorObservable with a user-facing error message
  return new ErrorObservable(
    'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
};
```

I think it is all that you can do, as the browser filters the error messages getting to your app.

Comment: Ok but I get the same error status if there is no connection with server and also if I make a get with a malformed link, like I have explained with status 0...Is it possible to avoid this or maybe to differentiate these errors?